# Does $a_k \rightarrow 0$ and partial sums of $a_n$ bounded mean there exists a finite series of all $a_n$'s?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let a sequence $(a_n)$ of real numbers be such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ and partial sums of the sequence are bounded. Then is it true that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ (series of the sequence) is of finite value? No permutation on the sequence is allowed when adding numbers.

Comment: If $a_n\ge0$ then this is true, but not in general.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following sequence $(a_k)_{k\geq 1}$:
$$1,-1,\ {1\over2},{1\over2},-{1\over2},-{1\over2},\ {1\over3},{1\over3},{1\over3},-{1\over3},-{1\over3},-{1\over3},\ {1\over4},{1\over4}{1\over4},{1\over4}, -{1\over4,},-{1\over4},\ldots$$
The $a_k$ tend to $0$ with $k\to\infty$, but their partial sums oscillate between $0$ and $1$ forever.Therefore the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ is divergent.